# filezilla: download times out

Tags: wireless-networking, filezilla

Since I've changed internet provider (from asdl to wireless) I experience weird behavior with filezilla: when I try to download a binary file it downloads a few hundred bytes, then times out:

```
Command:    RETR some_file
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 116,960 bytes in 23 seconds
```

And sometimes it works just fine! What could be the problem?

Comment: Could it be a connection-timeout set by the FTP server?

Comment: @Matt Clark I think it is, but why it happens...

Comment: Do you have access to the FTP server configuration?

Comment: @Matt Clark No, I don't. And I try it now - it works without me changing anything. Oh well, some mystery...